# убрать текст вне кавычек и удаление первой буквы каждой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Есть несколько строк в виде:

> ^aтипология творческих графических задач^fл туркина
>
> ^aобраз жизни перспективе идеальных типов личности разлома эпох^fа
>   романцов, пятилетова
>
> ^aпарадокс близости желания свете концептуализации любви философской
>   антропологии^fл пятилетова, заболотских
>
> ^aпорог ментальности женская эмансипация россии как дважды прерванный
>   проект^fв рассадникова, пятилетова

Как мне оставить только текст внутри ^ ^ и убрать первую букву "а" из каждой строки?

Comment: у вас там `^a` латинская, так и должно быть? :) похоже, да, раз есть `^f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В регулярке указываем границы и указываем группу символов `(.+?)`, которую хотим вытащить:

```
text = '^aтипология творческих графических задач^fл туркина'

import re
match = re.search(r'\^a(.+?)\^', text)
new_text = match.group(1)
print(new_text)  # 'типология творческих графических задач'
```

---

```
import re

text = '''\
^aтипология творческих графических задач^fл туркина
^aобраз жизни перспективе идеальных типов личности разлома эпох^fа романцов, пятилетова
^aпарадокс близости желания свете концептуализации любви философской антропологии^fл пятилетова, заболотских
^aпорог ментальности женская эмансипация россии как дважды прерванный проект^fв рассадникова, пятилетова
'''

items = re.findall(r'\^a(.+?)\^', text)
print(items)
```

Консоль:

```
['типология творческих графических задач', 'образ жизни перспективе идеальных типов личности разлома эпох', 'парадокс близости желания свете концептуализации любви философской антропологии', 'порог ментальности женская эмансипация россии как дважды прерванный проект']
```

Comment: А туркина куда дели?

Comment: @N.Turshiev, `необходимо оставить только текст внутри ^ ^ ` -- туркин не попадает в это условие

Comment: Судя по тексту он видимо нужен

Comment: По какому тексту?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но выходит ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Туркин не нужен

Comment: типология творческих графических задач  туркина
aобраз жизни перспективе идеальных типов личности разлома эпох романцов, пятилетова

Comment: Книга - автор
Книга - автор

Comment: @Ireen1985, так получится, если шаблон регулярки не совпал -- `match` будет хранить `None`. А как вы использовали мой пример? Добавил пример работы с куском текста из вопроса

Comment: Поправила, все сработало, но только для первой строки. Извините, я совсем новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне проделать тоже самое с остальными строками?

Comment: @Ireen1985, пробовали с findall?

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Все сработало!!!

Comment: @Ireen1985, если у вас целый текст, то можно его разбить на строки и в цикле для каждой строки вызвать код с `search`.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, буду иметь в виду

Comment: @Ireen1985, отметьте, тогда, вопрос как решенный :)